# Isolated on a Space Ship a Couple is trying to kill each other, both have blue blood

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

Remember seeing this on scifi as a kid. Maybe in the range of 2000-2010. A couple is aboard a spaceship travelling somewhere and it's their time to be awake to manage the ship and they catch a virus or something that turns their blood blue and they try to kill each other for some reason.

The movie ends with them flying the ship towards the sun to make sure the virus doesn't get to the destination. Would love to watch it as an adult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Alien Cargo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Cargo) (1999)

At the end....

> They decide to transfer the uninfected sleepers over with minutes to spare before their sleep chambers fail. **McNiel and Kaplan decide to remain with No.17 as it hurtles towards the sun, to prevent future contamination. To while away the time left, they dismantle the probe and discover that it contains a canister of the blue contaminant.** It is discovered that the probe was originally from Earth and they speculate that it picked up the virus in space and went on to accidentally contaminate an unknown alien race, who then sent the probe back where it came from as some kind of retaliation.

<sub>Flying into the sun</sub>